# Jquery effects not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

i am using a simple jquery image zoom effect on hover. it works fine in chrome, but effect is not shown in firefox and IE. The fadeIn works fine on all three.
i am using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#matter1').css("display", "none");
    $('#matter1').fadeIn(3000);
    $('img.img_zoom').hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            'zoom': 1.2
        }, 100);
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            'zoom': 1
        }, 100);
    });
    $('a.nav_font').hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            'zoom': 1.1
        }, 75);
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            'zoom': 1
        }, 75);
    });
});
</script>
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try the plugin with an older version of jQuery, like 1.8, and does that work ?

Comment: @adeneo:-just tried with 1.8.3 and it didn work. any other thoughts

Comment: You are using a plugin, right?

Comment: not plugin, just the function directly.

Comment: What makes you think `zoom` is a valid CSS property to animate ?

Comment: what do you suggest??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running this with the jQuery 1.x branch? jQuery 2 drops support for many older browsers

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this more, it appears that zoom is not supported in Firefox or IE. Instead, you would use:

```
-moz-transform: scale(x);
```

And in ie:

```
-ms-transform: scale(x);
```